# Add 2 numbers and show result on label with comma's

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, addition, client-side

I am writing some code for some functionality

My first text box

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtLeasePaymentFixed" type="text" runat="server" class="number" CssClass="form-control" Style="text-align: right" TabIndex="101"  placeholder="e.g 123,456,789"  onKeyUp="fncCalculateSum()" onBlur="fncCalculateSum()"></asp:TextBox>
```

My second text Box is

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtLeasePaymentVairable" type="text" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Style="text-align: right" TabIndex="102"  placeholder="e.g 123,456,789" onKeyUp="fncCalculateSum()" onBlur="fncCalculateSum()"></asp:TextBox>
```

Label On which Toltal shows is like this

```
   <asp:Label ID="lbltotal" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

Function calling onblur and onkeyUp is like this:

```
function fncCalculateSum() {


        var LeasePaymentFixed = $('#MainContent_txtLeasePaymentFixed');
        var LeasePaymentVariable = $('#MainContent_txtLeasePaymentVairable');
        if (LeasePaymentFixed.val() == '' || LeasePaymentFixed.val() == null) {
            PaymentFixed = 0;
        }
        else {
            PaymentFixed = parseFloat(LeasePaymentFixed.val());
        }
        if (LeasePaymentVariable.val() == '' || LeasePaymentVariable.val() == null) {
            PaymentVariable = 0;
        }
        else {
            PaymentVariable = parseFloat(LeasePaymentVariable.val());
        }


        (Sum) = PaymentFixed + PaymentVariable

        if ((LeasePaymentFixed.val().trim() == '' && LeasePaymentVariable.val().trim() == '') || (LeasePaymentFixed.val() == null && LeasePaymentVariable.val() == null)) {
            $("#MainContent_lbltotal").text('');
        }
        else {

            $("#MainContent_lbltotal").html(parseFloat(Sum));
        }

    }
```

Now I am using jQuery code to apply comma in international format after every 3 digits like this

```
        $('#MainContent_txtLeasePaymentFixed,#MainContent_txtLeasePaymentVairable,#MainContent_lbltotal').keyup(function(event){
            // skip for arrow keys
            if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40){
                event.preventDefault();
            }
            var $this = $(this);
            var num = $this.val().replace(/,/gi, "").split("").reverse().join("");

            var num2 = RemoveRougeChar(num.replace(/(.{3})/g,"$1,").split("").reverse().join(""));

            console.log(num2);


            // the following line has been simplified. Revision history contains original.
            $this.val(num2);
        });


        function RemoveRougeChar(convertString){


            if(convertString.substring(0,1) == ","){

                return convertString.substring(1, convertString.length)            

            }
            return convertString;

        }
```

When I write digits in the first text box it comes with commas, that's fine.
Same when I write in the second text box, but it don't show sum of all the digits on label.

Answer (score 0):

Watch out! You're losing data with your comma to `parseFloat` conversion:

```
let foo = 21231323.246;
let bar = foo.toLocaleString("en-US"); // "21,231,323.246"

console.log(parseFloat(bar)); // 21
```

You should check your conversions and make sure you're working on the right numbers.

Comment: Thanks I came to Know that Comma cant be in parseflot but than how can i pass the result and than convert it into parse float after that

Comment: I would probably store the value of the number (before formatting) in the [DOM element's dataset](http://html5demos.com/dataset) (e.g. `el.dataset.value = number;`). This way you can get the original value much more easily.